# iOS TWTweetComposeViewController - Posting in background

Tags: ios, twitter

I'm trying to integrate twitter in iOS5 app.
Using Twitter framework in my app, can I post the message in the background?
I know that using TWTweetComposeViewController, it will show a view and then it will post.
Is this possible?

Comment: [Here](http://dummycode.com/b/3) is a great post on integrating Twitter API with iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this using `TWTweetComposeViewController`. You can do this using `TWRequest` provided the user authorizes your app to access their Twitter account(s).

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no. The whole point of having the View Controller is to allow the User to see and dictate what exactly will be posted without interference from the App apart from the initial text which the user also has the option to change. It stops apps abusing the Twitter accounts from posting spam etc.

The [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Twitter/Reference/TWTweetSheetViewControllerClassRef/Reference/Reference.html) clearly states:

> Although you may perform Twitter requests on behalf of the user, you cannot append text, images, or URLs to tweets without the user’s knowledge. Hence, you can set the initial text and other content before presenting the tweet to the user but cannot change the tweet after the user views it.